# how to create aws instance and setup magento 2

Tags: database, elasticsearch, aws, git, magento2.4.4

I want to use aws EC2 service and RDS for database and going to setup magento 2 project using gitLab so anyone have idea then please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details about your expectations. AWS EC2 setup doesn't distinction from regular server setup. Just maybe you need to setup PHP 8.1 from non AMI repo.

Comment: I have created one magento store and i want to setup it on ubuntu os using virtual machine i am using windows os as my primary os. and i want to setup staging environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the some quite good links that may be useful for you

https://serverguy.com/magento/how-to-install-magento-on-aws/

https://yegorshytikov.medium.com/install-magento-2-on-aws-linux-2-d6419c7abecc

Comment: Hello Thank you for sharing but it is old steps i want current for newer version so can you have newer version idea then please share with me.